# Fetching data from REST API to Spark Dataframe using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

i am building a datapipeline which consume data from RESTApi in json format and pushed to Spark Dataframe. Spark Version: 2.4.4

but getting error as

```
df = SQLContext.jsonRDD(rdd) 
AttributeError: type object 'SQLContext' has no attribute 'jsonRDD'
```

Code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from urllib import urlopen
from pyspark import SQLContext
import json
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("DataCleansing") \
.getOrCreate()


def convert_single_object_per_line(json_list):
json_string = ""
for line in json_list:
json_string += json.dumps(line) + "\n"
return json_string

def parse_dataframe(json_data):
r = convert_single_object_per_line(json_data)
mylist = []
for line in r.splitlines():
mylist.append(line)
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(mylist)
df = SQLContext.jsonRDD(rdd)
return df

url = "https://mylink"
response = urlopen(url)
data = str(response.read())
json_data = json.loads(data)
df = parse_dataframe(json_data)
```

if there is any other better way to query RestApi and bring data to Spark Dataframe using Pyspark.

I am not sure if i am missing something.

Comment: There is rest api datasource for spark, check this - https://github.com/sourav-mazumder/Data-Science-Extensions/tree/master/spark-datasource-rest

Comment: did you use the 'REST API datasource' to implement parallel requests?

Comment: updated import:
from urllib.request import urlopen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check Spark [Rest API](https://github.com/sourav-mazumder/Data-Science-Extensions/tree/master/spark-datasource-rest) Data source. One advantage with this library is it will use multiple executors to fetch data rest api & create data frame for you.

In your code, you are fetching all data into the driver & creating DataFrame, It might fail with heap space if you have very huge data.

```
url = "https://mylink"
options = { 'url' : url, 'method' : 'GET', 'readTimeout' : '10000', 'connectionTimeout' : '2000', 'partitions' : '10'}
```

```
# Now we create the Dataframe which contains the result from the call to the API
df = spark.read.format("org.apache.dsext.spark.datasource.rest.RestDataSource").options(**options).load()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216656/discussion-on-answer-by-srinivas-fetching-data-from-rest-api-to-spark-dataframe).

Comment: great. wheres the conversation now ?

Comment: Please note that the RestDataSource library depends on scalaj_http package that is now deprecated as reported here https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http

Comment: yes. I got it..